# ArcGIS planarize vs autofixing "must not intersect or touch interior" topology

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology, cluster-tolerance

trying to fix topology errors in OSM here.  I am wondering whether ArcGIS planarize is essentially the same as creating a topology that says a class must not intersect or touch interior.  Then autofixing all those errors?

One difference I can see is that the topology allows you to use multiple classes; thus you shouldn't break relationships to other classes by a topology fix whereas it might happen in planarize when e.g. two points closer than cluster tolerance are snapped together.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what is going on here?

---

I think I may have found out already.  ArcMap hangs trying to autofix 50,000 topology errors, it may or may not finish the job but I didn't wait to find out.  It can handle a planarize though.  That suggests the algorithms used are different.